# How to rotate a series of lines and shapes drawn in drawing Panel?

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, awt, panel

I am wondering how to rotate things I have already drawn (like lines) in Java drawing `Panel` (**not** in `JPanel`).

I am trying to rotate a triangle i created by connecting 3 lines:

```
g.drawLine(size, size, 2*size, size);
g.drawLine(size, size,size+size/2, size+(int)(size/2 * Math.sqrt(3)));
g.drawLine(2*size, size,size+size/2, size+(int)(size/2 * Math.sqrt(3)));
```

How do I rotate that?

Comment: 1) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html). 2) Use an `AffineTransform` - though note that won't apply to things that are 'already drawn'.  It will be necessary to repaint the panel.

Comment: this is for class so my teacher requires i use awt,
can you provide an example of how to rotate a single line using affineTransform

Comment: *"..can you provide an example"*  I have provided [many examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A418556+affinetransform) already.  If you cannot get a working solution from those examples, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rotate a point like that, then you could:

```
double startX; // <------------|
double startY; // <------------|
double endX;   // <------------|
double endY;   // <-define these
double angle;  // the angle of rotation in degrees
```

To draw the original line

```
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY); //this is the original line

double length = Math.pow(Math.pow(startX-endX,2)+Math.pow(startY-endY,2),0.5);
double xChange = length * cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
double yChange = length * sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
```

To draw the new, rotated line

```
g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
g.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000); //paint over it

g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawLine(startX, startY, endX + xChange, endY + yChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use graphics2D and Polygons

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
int x2Points[] = {0, 100, 0, 100}; //these are the X coordinates
int y2Points[] = {0, 50, 50, 0}; //these are the Y coordinates
GeneralPath polyline = 
        new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, x2Points.length);

polyline.moveTo (x2Points[0], y2Points[0]);

for (int index = 1; index < x2Points.length; index++) {
         polyline.lineTo(x2Points[index], y2Points[index]);
};

g2.draw(polyline);
```

If you want to rotate it, just do it over but add, before

```
g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), centerX, centerY);
```

Where "angle" is the amount you want to rotate it and (centerX, centerY) are the coordinates of the point you want to rotate it around.

I hope this helps

Comment: this is great but i literally just want to rotate a single line by a set amount of degrees while still keeping the original point the line starts at the same

Comment: @LouisB It turns out that it's less trivial than it sounds. You either use Graphics2D.rotate() or do it yourself with some basic trig.